# I am trying on making my txt file input each line on a URL API, but no error messages receive and wont run correctly

Tags: python, list, python-requests, numbers

I'm trying to make the bot open my txt file and go into a for loop into a API and repeat the process of doing that, and I receive no error message but I know it doesn't do the following.

```
listOfIDs = [] #Defines list of ids to add ids into.
document = open(r"D:\untitled\Lib/Babahani.txt") #Opens the txt file containing the ids
for line in document: #For every line in the txt document...
  listOfIDs.append(line) #Add the line to listOfIDs
document.close() #close the txt file.

for id in listOfIDs: #For every id in listOfIDs
  requests.post(url="https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/(userID)/follow" + id, params={"100"}) #Do the request with the id.
```

Also the txt file I wanted my bot to put each row is its own url for example the first one is 29661084 so

```
https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/(29661084)/follow
```

Here is the txt

```
29661084
2736666
9509309
9933671
1484736
10026270
559756
6160107
7706434
1335986
2865714
28726703
28831772
11228237
27492063
581810
1584515
15163436
2326863
20499307
1240373
2586711
1866701
18317186
3178198
23179837
2287710
322669
14228847
2247182
27672373
20531529
21635271
13338291
104762
7974332
23622281
21677451
98526
401749
13678128
15305170
10940721
8574760
2658940
2779406
2574610
1228444
3797733
13237058
10515294
25677902
2673170
9954375
14971177
155477
16346150
6717032
1536928
24026181
17421257
21313944
8263228
21298667
16997787
31867746
3562742
7206716
18485577
21502919
7314755
28488398
4219808
29167399
23298266
11348402
9123233
33310193
2297692
20446427
33320719
24544521
33242143
17984201
14984728
23824776
2392219
16055802
17946977
562110
19228563
25017090
14080735
23471210
25929393
34683701
8013004
7331182
31619684
23947076
```

Comment: Have you tried getting just a single url working before doing the whole thing with files, and loops, etc? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: yes it has worked when I made the single url, before i've created this

Comment: So does this work?:  `requests.post(url="https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/(29661084)/follow", params={"100"})`

Comment: Yes you can also remove the ", params=100" and it will work fine also

Comment: In your code what is the `+ id` meant to do? And what does `(userID)` mean?

Comment: Does this work: `requests.post(url="https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/(userID)/follow29661084", params={"100"})`

Comment: The "id" is for every single ID in the txt, and userID is the ID you want it to follow which is also the id

Comment: I dont think it works no..

Comment: Why would Python know the signifcance of `userID`?

Comment: No clue... So it should be 
```
requests.post(url="https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/29661084/follow", params={"100"}
```

Comment: Or if u want to loop requests.post(url="friends.roblox.com/v1/users/" + id + "/follow", params={"100"}

Comment: Looks good. You could also use a format string: `f'https://friends.roblox.com/v1/users/{id}/follow'`